# Optimize count query in Django

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have the following queries:

```
files = DataAvailability.objects.all()
type1 = files.filter(type1=True)
type2 = files.filter(type2=True)

# People information
people = Person.objects.all()
users = people.filter(is_subject=True)

# count information (this is taking a long time to query them all)
type1_users = type1.filter(person__in=users).count()
type2_users = type2.filter(person__in=users).count()
total_users = files.filter(person__in=users).count()
# another way
total_users2 = files.filter(person__in=users)
type1_users2 = total_users.filter(type1=True).count()
type2_users2 = total_users.filter(type2=True).count()
total_count = total_users2.count()
```

I thought about creating a query with `.values()` and putting into a `set()`. 
After that is done execute some functions within the set (like diff).

Is this the only way to improve the query time?

Comment: do you have `db_index=True` on foreign key fields?

Comment: Oh. And maybe you could `type1.filter(person__is_subject=True)`?

Comment: All the fields that are being searched are indexed. The thing is that it has too many files and for each count() it does one query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have to make those queries very often (once a day at most). So I'm running on a cron job which exports the data to a file (you could create a table in your database for auditing purposes, for ex). I then read the file and use the data from there. It's working well/fast.

Answer (score 1):

You can always do raw SQL https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries

Example:

```
# Dont do this its insecure
YourModel.objects.raw(f"select id from {YourModel._meta.db_table}") 

# Do like this to avoid SQL injection issues.
YourModel.objects.raw("select id from app_model_name")
```

The name of the table can be obtained as: `YourModel._meta.db_table` and also you can get the sql of a queryset like this:

```
type1_users = type1.filter(person__in=users)
type1_users.query.__str__()
```

So you can build join this query to another one.

Comment: True, thanks! I just like to avoid building raw queries. The reason I avoid is mainly to discourage other ppl to do the same

Comment: I understand your reasons, the effort of maintenance increases using raw sql, if some time you need to manage many custom queries between different apps and control the access for each query you  should try something like: [metabase](https://www.metabase.com) so all  your custom queries can be central managed and you can include iframes from metabase in every app you need it.

Comment: Precisely! That's neat I will def check it out!